# Share an Xcode project as a static library for other people to use in emulator. How do you use an AppDelegate from a .a static library file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I want to share my Xcode project as a static library for other people to use in the xcode emulator (giving them as little raw source code as possible).  How do you use an AppDelegate from a .a library file in Xcode or UIBuilder?

I copied the main Window.xib file to a new project and included all of the other source files in a static .a library that I thought I would be able to invoke somehow.  What do I have to do to launch my main product that is compiled into the .a library from a brand new Xcode project that is including that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a much better solution found in someone else's question:
[iOS Question. Can I distribute the Xcode simulator versions of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104127/ios-question-can-i-distribute-the-xcode-simulator-versions-of-my-app)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to link to the static library. Include it in your new Xcode project, and then in the target for the application, go to the General tab and set the library as linked. You'll probably want to copy it into your new project's bundle (in the Frameworks directory), using a Copy Files build phase. You'll also need to reference the header files for the static library for avoid warnings.