# Can you install an Ad-Hoc iPad distribution on an iPad emulator?

Tags: xcode, ipad

Can you install an Ad-Hoc iPad distribution on an iPad emulator?

Update: Please see: [iOS Question. Can I distribute the Xcode simulator versions of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104127/ios-question-can-i-distribute-the-xcode-simulator-versions-of-my-app)

Comment: Answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104127/ios-question-can-i-distribute-the-xcode-simulator-versions-of-my-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer basically gives the ability to distribute an emulator version of the application (tackles the main requirement of my question.):

[iOS Question. Can I distribute the Xcode simulator versions of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104127/ios-question-can-i-distribute-the-xcode-simulator-versions-of-my-app)

Answer (score 1):

No, because they are compiled for different processor architectures.